Hide physical URLs from search Yes/No different while adding a page
While i am creating a page from settings Settings-> Add a Page i see Hide physical URLs from search as Yes. When i checked the Version History i see Title and "Hide physical URLs from search" changes. Default is no but After when i enter the Title of the page it changes.
While adding a page from Site Contents->Pages "New" button it does not do that.
Does anyone knows why "Hide physical URLs from search" becomes yes while i am creating a page from settings ?
I check the Site Settings → Search and Offline Availability
Allow this site to appear in search results: → Yes by default.
